# how to calculate proportion between two numbers instead fixed steps

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create an effect that set camera distance from player according to his movement speed.

This code works but I'm using fixed number steps.

```
    var movingSpeed = playerObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().velocity.magnitude;
    var cFollow = mainCamera.GetComponent<Follow>();

    if(movingSpeed > 3.5){
        cCameraController.DesiredDistance = 2.3f;
        cFollow.TiltVector = new Vector3(0f, -0.4f, 0f);
    }else if(axis == 2.8){
        cCameraController.DesiredDistance = 1.9f;
        cFollow.TiltVector = new Vector3(0f, -0.3f, 0f);
    }else if(axis == 1.8){
        cCameraController.DesiredDistance = 1.5f;
        cFollow.TiltVector = new Vector3(0f, -0.2f, 0f);
    }else{
        cCameraController.DesiredDistance = 1.1f;
        cFollow.TiltVector = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f);
    }
```

I'm running this code on InvokeRepeat 1 second and its not good because is not smooth.

So, is there any way to calculate those numbers proportionally so I can use it on Update() for a better smooth and constant adjustment?

Comment: Not an answer to your question,  but... You need to understand that floating point numbers (`float` and `double`) are approximations. You shouldn't be testing for equality like you are. Instead, check that the absolute value of the difference of the two numbers is _close enough_ (the value of _close enough_ is known as _epsilon_ and can vary based on your requirements). Change your code to something like `else if(Math.Abs(axis-2.8) < epsilon)`. You probably want to make that comparison into a function

Comment: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Lerp.html and https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html may be what you are looking for.

Comment: Also, consider using the `Time` class for smoothing every frame.

Answer (score 0):

im not sure what the "axis" variable is in your code. As far as i understand your problem. you should be able to calculate the distance and tilt with a math funtion. for the distance i would choose either a linear or power function . here are some examples. i dont have many values to work with so these might need to tweek those

```
//linear
float desiredDistance = 1.1f + 0.37f*movingSpeed;

//power
float desiredDistance = 1.1 + Math.pow(movingSpeed,0.2);
```

with the distance you can calculate the tilt. i have tried to make a rough estimate with the given values. its not excact though

```
cFollow.TiltVector = new Vector3(0f, -Math.sqrt(0.1*DesiredDistance-0.1), 0f);
```

hope this helps